# Dropdown Submenus in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I wanted to make Dropdown Submenus similar to how they have it in bootstrap as denoted on this link under `dropdown-submenu`.

http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html#dropdowns

Anyways I was wondering, is there anyway integrate or incorporate this into my application via AngularJS? My code is as follows for creating a dropdown that I wanted. For each entry inside my dropdown, I wanted to create a submenu that, once you hover over them, you would be able to view the submenu (which would be the same for every entry). The following is my code for the dropdown:

```
<select class="span4" ng-model="create.activityTypeName" multiple ng-options="value for value in activityTypes" data-style="btn" bs-select></select>
```

This dropdown allows me to select multiple entries from the `create.activityTypeName` array I have created.

If anyone could help me out, that would be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use the HTML that bootstrap supports, which appears to be nested unordered lists.

I'm not entirely sure what your `create.activityTypeName` data structure is, but I got an example working using a few `ng-repeat` directives. Your array would replace `$scope.items` in the example.

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sp6bL/